# ImageMagick PDF error

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick-6.2.8, I want to simply load a PDF:

```
<?php
  $imagick = new imagick('aleister-crowley.pdf');
?>
```

but I receive error (Firefox):
"The connection was reset"

I've test other supported file extensions, but PDF...

Please help.

Comment: what errors do you get you execute the PHP from the command line?